# Do redirects prevent page tracking in Google Analytics?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-analytics

I have an mvc3 app that uses a lot of redirects so the URL path is not displayed to the user.  When they go through the app they don't see any changes in the url.

Will google analytics still track the separate pages?

Comment: What do you mean with "redirects"? (Because redirecting the way I understand, clients still see the URL.) Besides, ASP.NET MVC doesn't have much to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics tracking is javascript and it needs to run on the page in the browser in the traditional set up provided by GA documentation.

If the redirect does not include the GA js or leaves the page so fast that the GA js can not run, then no, it will not track the separate pages. Assuming, of course, this is a traditional redirect.

Redirects usually display in the browser unless there is URL rewriting going on.

You can install the [GA debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) and Chrome and run the page to see if a tracking beacon is sent.